# How to get remote_addr with responder?

Tags: python, web, server, frameworks, web-frameworks

I'm working with responder the python web framework and trying to get remote_addr.

I looked `req.header` but there's no data. No `client` or `remote_addr` field in `req`.
And I googled for a while but I didn't get any information.

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First argument of the handler (declare it `req` commonly) stores `starlette.requests.Request` in `req._starlette`.
So we can get `remote_addr` by looking at `req._starlette.client.host`.

Additionally, we can get `remote_addr` from `WebSocket` object by `ws.scope["client"][0]` (index 1 is the port).

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate on your answer a bit more?